# CDC and ETL help/recommendations

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, etl, cdc

Here's the background.

We have a few different customers, each with a different backend source database.  We want to be back to pick up real time changes to the backend database, then transform the data to a target schema in our target database.  After that broadcast a message to other apps alerting the change.

To do this we need CDC software for the change detection and then a good ETL tool to transform and load the data into the target database.

So far we have looked at IBM's CDC.  Research is still in the preliminary stages but I just wanted to get other people's take on this.  What programs do you recommend for this?  Are we even going about this the right way...meaning is CDC software overkill?

Answer (score 0):

Most databases have some sort of built-in CDC mechanism(Oracle does for sure).  I would consider applying the Pub/Sub pattern and making each DB a publisher and have the target subscribe to all of changes.  Other apps could also subscribe to further notifications.  NServiceBus is a good option for this kind of communication.  If you don't want to use a native DB CDC mechanism then you could do something primitive and build something to detect changes per DB vendor(triggers, inspecting redo logs, or other).